# how to get individual array element from perl

Tags: perl

Following is the output of the `Dumper($resultSet);`

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'rows' => [
                             bless( {
                                      'columns' => [
                                                     bless( {
                                                              'columnName' => 'TABLESCHEMANAME',
                                                              'columnValue' => 'FROM_PERL'
                                                            }, 'abc::TColumn' )
                                                   ]
                                    }, 'abc::TRow' )
                           ]
               }, 'abc::TResultSet' );
```

How Do I iterators over `columns` arrays.

Answer (score 3):

The data you want to access is encapsulated in an object of type `abc::TResultSet`. This class should have an API to allow access to its members. It is generally a bad idea to circumvent encapsulation, even if you could do so quite easily.

---

If you weren't dealing with objects but just nested data stuctures, you can retrieve the arrayref you want, and dereference it to loop over it:

```
for my $row (@{ $VAR1->{rows} }) {
  for my $cell (@{ $row->{columns} }) {
    my ($name, $value) = @{$cell}{qw/columnName columnValue/}; # a hash slice
    ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: TResultSet is returned by the apache thrift call. package abc::TResultSet;
use base qw(Class::Accessor);
abc::TResultSet->mk_accessors( qw( rows ) );